# Comment comprendre cette phrase « un événement dont s'attend à ce qu'il ait lieu » ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Je suis tombé sur la définition suivante de « sans pour autant » sur [linternaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/sans-pour-autant/):

> Dans la phrase, précède un événement dont s'attend à ce qu'il ait lieu mais qui n'est finalement pas vérifié.

Sémantiquement, je comprends ce qu'elle veut dire mais grammaticalement, j'ai du mal à analyser le segment « un événement dont s'attend à ce qu'il ait lieu ». Je pense que ça signifie un événement qu'on attend mais je ne comprends pas l'usage de « dont » ici.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il y a une erreur dans cette phrase sur l'Internaute, il manque un sujet. La phrase correcte est la suivante :

> Dans la phrase, précède un événement dont **on** s'attend à ce qu'il ait lieu mais qui n'est finalement pas vérifié.

> [...] an event that **we** expect to happen [...]

Avec ce sujet, on retrouve donc une construction plus classique (bien qu'un peu complexe) avec le pronom relatif "dont" suivi du bloc subordonné. Une version plus simple pourrait être :

> Dans la phrase, précède un événement **auquel** on s'attend mais qui n'est finalement pas vérifié.

Voici quelques liens en complément d'information sur l'usage de [dont](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont//0) et des [pronoms](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-relatifs) [relatifs](https://www.lepointdufle.net/p/pronomsrelatifs.htm) de façon générale.

Comment: Merci pour votre explication !

Answer (score 1):

Pour en rajouter une couche, la formulation est problématique car elle combine deux construction qui s'excluent mutuellement:

1. *s'attendre à quelque chose*
2. *attendre de quelqu'un/quelque chose qu'il/elle [+subordonnée]*

La formulation correcte serait donc ultimement ou bien (comme le note Reyedy) *un événement auquel on s'attend* ou, de manière à mon avis inutilement alambiquée (et qui mène ultimement à une double faute): *un événement dont on attend qu'il ait lieu*.

Comment: Merci pour votre remarque ! Moi aussi, je trouve la formulation alambiquée.